# Dealing with wrong projection

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I am working with some rasters that have been produced with a wrong projection.
The Spatial Reference is saved as WGS84 (EPSG:4326) but the unit are clearly in meters and not degrees. I have tried both with ArcMap and QGIS.

If I try to project to UTM, something happens but the units are clearly degrees.

Is there a way to force, or manually overwrite the projection?

Unfortunately there's no chance to get the correct data from the source that sent them to me.

Comment: So... are the units clearly degrees, or clearly meters?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: @Erik They are clearly wrong, showing degrees range unit when the SR should show meters and vice versa

Comment: @PolyGeo, I am using both QGIS and Arcmap, but now looking for a solution also in R

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the original raster extent and possibly a screenshot of the data, plus a general idea of the location the data represents if it's not obvious.

Comment: And what kind of raster do you have - a tiff with a world file, a geotiff, and ESRI GRID?

Comment: Please decide which of ArcMap, QGIS and R you wish to ask about in this particular question. That way you can describe precisely what you have tried. You can always ask about another product in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way "to force, or manually overwrite the projection." Open the layer properties, and change its CRS. Save a copy of the raster. The saved copy should have the new CRS set as its default. The process is basically the same in both QGIS and ArcGIS softwares.

You should only do this if:

1. You are absolutely certain the new projection is the correct, native projection of the data
2. You have not already re-projected the layer.

Whether or not this is actually the solution to your problem is not clear. If you want help further troubleshooting your raster, please edit your question to provide the information and sample data requested in the comments.